# Able to go to WordPress admin even after deleting auth cookies from request headers

Tags: security

I discovered that if I remove my auth cookies from my browser's request header, I am still able to view a page.

Steps:

1. Log into my WordPress installation
2. Go to the wp-admin page
3. In Chrome, use the developer Network tab and copy the headers for
   accessing a page
4. Paste the cookie into Dev HTTP Client
5. Remove all the cookies
6. Press SEND
7. The output reveals that I am still able to access the admin page

Is this a vulnerability? If I have removed the auth cookies, shouldn't WordPress be able to retrieve the logged in user?

Comment: Is this question not a better fit for the WordPress support forums? This reads more like a potential bug report than a question for the stack exchange network.

Comment: IMO, you are not clearing out ALL the cookies.  There are session cookies and domain cookies

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the Cookie header, Dev HTTP Client still sends whatever cookies you have for that site. You can verify this with [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com)